# Cycle to retrieve elements under the matrix diagonal using Python Numpy with array indexing

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix-indexing

within my Pyhton code, with the variable `i` I denote the row of the matrix `A`.
In every step, I want to retrieve all the elements before the diagonal current element `A[i,i]`.

this is the code I used through [array indexing](http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#numpy-array-indexing) :

```
import numpy as np 

A = np.array([
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]
])

n = 3;

for i in range (n):
  print(A[i,0:i-1])
```

I wrote this particular code, following my reasoning:

```
i=0) A[0, 0:-1] = doesn't exists a column -1 so this retrieves   []
i=1) A[1, 0:1-1] = A[1,0:0] → A[1,0] = 4                         [4]
i=2) A[2, 0:2-1] = A[2,0:1] → A[2,0] = 7 and A[2,1] = 8          [7 8]
```

So the output I expect would be:

```
[]
[4]
[7 8]
```

instead I obtain the following unwanted output:

```
[1 2]
[]
[7]
```

Please can you tell me, where is the error? How can I obtain the correct result? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the index you identify.

```
print(A[i,0:i-1])
```

When you identify an ending index in Python, the value you identify is excluded. So 0:3 would yield index 0, 1, and 2.  You do not need the -1 you added.  Also, in Python, index -1 means start by the end.  So in your code, when i = 0, you get 0:-1 which means all from 0 to last index (excluded).

Change your print to this :

```
print(A[i,0:i])
```